# C# SerialPort settings

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, serial-port

I'm having trouble in setting up the COM port using the `SerialPort` class. There are a number of settings that get set differently than I need them to be when I call the `SerialPort` constructor. Using a port monitor application I have noticed the following:

1. ReadIntervalTimeout = -1 (should be
   0)
2. ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = -1
   (should be 0)
3. ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000
   (should be 0)
4. WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0 (OK)
5. WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0 (OK)
6. EoFChar = 26 (should be 0)
7. ErrorChar = 63 (should be 0)
8. Break char = 63 (should be 0)
9. XOn Limit = 1024 (should be 2048)
10. XOff Limit = 1024 (should be 512)
11. FlowReplace = 0x87 (should be 0)

How do I change these settings (I'm using C#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values cannot be set with the SerialPort wrapper class. It is an incomplete wrapper. You can look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/89B88E89-5814-4819-8B50-7CAA3FAF5F54) for an example of changing the XON and XOFF characters. For the rest you'll have to refer to the [DCB documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363214.aspx).

**Updated**

The DCB flag values are bit fields in the DCB structure.

```
DWORD fBinary  :1;            // Bit 0
DWORD fParity  :1;            // Bit 1
DWORD fOutxCtsFlow  :1;       // Bit 2
DWORD fOutxDsrFlow  :1;       // Bit 3
DWORD fDtrControl  :2;        // Bit 4 - 5
DWORD fDsrSensitivity  :1;    // Bit 6
DWORD fTXContinueOnXoff  :1;  // Bit 7
DWORD fOutX  :1;              // Bit 8
DWORD fInX  :1;               // Bit 9
DWORD fErrorChar  :1;         // Bit 10
DWORD fNull  :1;              // Bit 11
DWORD fRtsControl  :2;        // Bit 12 - 13
DWORD fAbortOnError  :1;      // Bit 14
DWORD fDummy2  :17;           // Bit 15 - 31
```

And in case you were wondering how SetDcbFlag figures out which bits you're manipulating, here it is (courtesy of Reflector):

```
internal void SetDcbFlag(int whichFlag, int setting)
{
    uint mask;
    if ((whichFlag == 4) || (whichFlag == 12))
        mask = 3;
    else if (whichFlag == 15)
        mask = 0x1ffff;
    else
        mask = 1;
    this.dcb.Flags &= ~(mask << whichFlag);
    this.dcb.Flags |= ((uint)setting << whichFlag);
}
```

You can see that for Bit #4 or #12 it uses a 2-bit mask, for Bit #15 a 17-bit mask, and for the rest a 1-bit mask.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) on the [`SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class provides details on how to configure the port. I recommend that you read through this information.

However, to get you started, here is how you would change the read timeout:

```
port.ReadTimeout = 0;
```

That said, not all the characteristics you mention can be configured via .NET without getting a little (okay, a lot) dirty with [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx) and interacting with the port using the Win32 API ([`Communications Functions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363194%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)) rather than [`SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx). However, you may want to consider whether .NET is the appropriate platform if you need to change characteristics not wrapped by the `SerialPort` class.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers, they certainly put me on the right track. Unfortunately using C# or another language is not my decision, so I had to do it in C# somehow.

Using the reflection hack that Tergiver provided [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharpgeneral/thread/89B88E89-5814-4819-8B50-7CAA3FAF5F54) I have been able to set most of the properties found in the DCB structure. I found out that ErrorChar and BreakChar can be easily set by assigning the needed value to SerialPort.ParityReplace although this does not seem obvious at all in my opinion.

Setting the timeouts was an easy job by using the same hack, the COMMTIMEOUTS structure and p/Invoking SetCommTimeouts.

For flow control it was a little tricky because this is done internally by SetCommState by a call to DeviceIoControl. My problem was that I couldn't really make the connection between the DCB flags, ControlHandShake and FlowReplace. I couldn't find documentation about the order of the flags in the 32-bit DCB structure so I've set the whole Flags property to 0. This causes ControlHandShake and FlowReplace to be 0 in the end.

Data sending/receiving seems to work fine, I hope I didn't omit something here.

Comment: The flags are documented in the DCB link I gave you. The DCB structure uses C/C++ bitfields. However, I also have a reflection hack showing how to alter the flags here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/45a89532-b01c-4ef8-aa46-532882cec004

Comment: I updated my comment above to show the values (Bit #) to pass to `SetDcbFlag` in the link I gave above.